# Channel.send for slash commands

Tags: nextcord

Im migrating my commands to slash variants and for some i need to send message to a different channel,i need the await channel.send() in nextcord slash,something like

```
channel = client.get_channel(862547191373496380)
await interaction.response.channel.send_message()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use

```
await channel.send()
```

Note that this will not respond to the slash command, but rather, send a separate message in the specified channel.

Answer (score -1):

for the response, you can simply do this:

```
await channel.response.send_message()
```

Comment: This would result in an `AttributeError`, `TextChannel.response` does not exist, see:

[nextcord.TextChannel](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel)